# Change color of overlayimage only instead of the whole canvas Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas where i have a background image of transparent t-shirt. Now i want to change the color of tshirt dynamically and in order to do that the one can change the color of canvas background and the shirt will adapt to it. my canvas is around 920 Width and 570 height and the background image is 530 width and 630 height and it is in the center of the canvas

Now i only want to change the color of image background so that the extra bar of canvas is not colored

The results that i am getting

[image]

The results that i want

[image]

What i have tried is tried using overlaycolor image of fabricjs library but none of them are working for me. i tried to give left:190 in setBackgroungColor of Fabric library but that is not working either.

any help in this matter is appreciated

```
<div id="shirtDiv">
                    <canvas id="tcanvas"></canvas>
</div>


<script>
var canvas;
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas',{backgroundColor:'red', floodColor:'red'});
    canvas.setHeight(570);
    canvas.setWidth(926);
    canvas.setOverlayImage('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/m96GqS_oGOQQPt4TMfxYQtrFfdRN6IcgkMQ-y4t_9DVDpSLsGv-2PXdX_NvjP1ljsgw680RuzZBiURQgzPSnWxmX1hU',canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),{
        top:25,
        left:190
    });
    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

here is the code in : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94gaxyc7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fabric.Image.backgroundColor`.
Will paint the area of the image of a color ( or a gradient ) before panting the image.

```js
var canvas;
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas');
    canvas.setHeight(570);
    canvas.setWidth(926);
    canvas.setOverlayImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/printio.png', function() {
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
  canvas.overlayImage.backgroundColor = 'red';
}, {
        top:25,
        left:190
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="shirtDiv">
                    <canvas id="tcanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is correct and thanks for that but i have another problem now 
my canvas have objects and i was using the transparency of this shirt image to view the objects only inside the shirt and the background color of DIV (old method) was low in z-index so now after applying `overlayImage.backgroundColor` the objects are not showing on the overlayed image. is there a way where i can size the `backgroundImage` color of canvas or make the object z-index above **overlayed image color** but below the actual image. sorry for the trouble

Comment: What about using a backgroundImage for the canvas as a red rectangle, the same size of the transparent tshirt that you will put as overlayImage, and in the middle you put what you want? like a sandwitch with red as bottom layer, tshirt as top layer, all the rest in the middle.

Comment: i already tried this solution yesterday but didn't thought that setting rect as backgroundimage would be possible i wasn't thinking much anyway i did this and it works like a charm thank you so much